# How to create shapes in table based on key

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server

I have a shapefile with every building on campus and a key(BUILDCODE), I have a table with the number of people per building and time of the measurement. I am trying to create a time enabled layer that will show the population in each building per day. My problem is that each building only has one shape in the shapefile, do I need to create a unique instance of every building per measurement or is there a simple way to associate one building to a series of measurements?

Thanks

Comment: What version of ArcGIS do you have? DO you want a Desktop solution? or something to do with a Web Solution?

Comment: You don't need the temporal data in the same table as the geometry. See this page for more details: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Temporal_data_in_separate_tables/005z0000001w000000/